# I couldnt call a value from other function

Tags: javascript

The js code has 3 functions. I want to call values from the 2 functions and execute them in the 3rd function.

```js
function first() {

  var x = 2
  var y = 3
  var z = x * y
}
first()

function second() {
  first();
  var z;
  var a = z - 1
}
second()

function third() {
  first();
  second();

  var a
  var z
  var ans = a * z

  console.log(ans);
  document.getElementById("ans_html").innerHTML = precision(ans);
}
third()
```

```html
<div id="ans_html"></div>
```

The expected outcome was 30.

But the output was "NaN".

Comment: `"message": "ReferenceError: precision is not defined",`

Comment: The variables that you use in each of the three functions are *local* to that function; they are not accessible by the other functions. So for example the `z` in `second` is undefined. It is not influenced by the call of `first`.

Comment: Because that's not how things work, you need to read a little more about function parameters and how a function works.

Comment: precision is defined in other js file. it works for my previous work

Comment: So many concepts wrong here it's hard to know where to start. Definitely need to read up on variable scope in javscript

Answer (score 1):

In most languages, including JS, variables have "scope" ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)). If you want to share data between function's, you can either

1) return values ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)),

```js
function first() {
  var x = 2
  var y = 3
  return x * y;
}

function second() {
  let z = first();
  return z - 1
}

function third() {
  let z = first();
  let a = second();

  var ans = a * z

  console.log(ans);
}
third();
```

2), less conventionally, modify a param obj since they're are passed by ref.

```js
let func = param => {
  param.x = 3;
  param.y = 4;
};

let a = {};
func(a);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either create global variables which is considered a bad practice, or pass values around as parameters.

Global variables:

```
var a
var x
var y
var z
function first() {
    x = 2
    y = 3
    z = x * y
}
function second() {
    a = z - 1
}
function third() {
    first()
    second()
    let ans = a * z

    console.log(ans);
}
```

Passing Parameters:

```
function first(x, y) {
    return x * y
}
function second(z) {
    return z - 1
}
function third() {
    let x = 2
    let y = 3
    let z = first(x, y)
    let a = second(z)

    let ans = a * z

    console.log(ans);
}
```

Judging based on your code, you likely should take a look into how JavaScript scopes variables based on using the keyword `var` vs `let`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have two major issues:

1. Your variables `a` and `z` are not global variables. They are defined within the function itself so you cannot access those variables outside of that scope (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope))
2. I would not fix your code to adhere to the first issue. You don't need global variables here, you just need to return the result so you can call your functions later. In the long run, I would assume you want to add arguments to your functions, but the below is an example of how to do what you're trying to accomplish by simply returning the result in your functions.

**NOTE** I don't know if you have a custom `precision` function or what. So, I added an empty function that just returns the input. You can probably remove this.

```js
function precision(num) {
 // Insert whatever is in your precision function here...
 return num;
}

function first() {
  var x = 2
  var y = 3
  var z = x * y
  return z;
}

function second() {
  var z = first();
  var a = z - 1
  return a;
}

function third() {
  var a = second();
  var z = first();
  var ans = a * z

  console.log(ans);
  document.getElementById("ans_html").innerHTML = precision(ans);
}
third()
```

```html
<div id="ans_html"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best design pattern, but if you want to achieve this in this way, the code is going to look like the one below. You need to return the result of the function in order to get it in another function and use it.

```js
function first() {
  var x = 2
  var y = 3
  return x * y
}

function second() {
  var z = first()
  return z - 1
}

function third() {
  var a = first()
  var z = second()
  var ans = a * z

  console.log(ans);
  // document.getElementById("ans_html").innerHTML = precision(ans);
}
third()
```

```html
<div id="ans_html"></div>
```